# Xcode 4.3.2 problems using git

Tags: git, version-control, xcode4.3

Hello Stackoverflow fellows,

Since I installed Xcode 4.3.2 I'm having a lot of problems using git. The File->Source Controls commands doesn't work properly, but if I use git on console then things work well.

So I decided to not check "Create local go repository for this project" for my new projects. To my surprise Xcode start to complain when:

- I try to delete files with the message "fatal: Not a git repository (or any the parent directories):.git"
- I try to rename a file with the message "fatal: Not a git repository (or any the parent directories):.git"
- I try to refactory->rename a class with the message "Unable to rename Class.m to Cl.m"

Anybody knows what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks in advanced,

Gazolla

Comment: yeah, in Console git works fine.

Comment: Sorry, I meant Console.app; have a look at the system logs to see if Xcode is trying to tell you anything.

Comment: Nothing on the Console.app :-(

Comment: It seems that xcode think that the project is using a git repository. I'm saying that because when I ran the command "git status" on Terminal then gits said to me the same message:"fatal: Not a git repository (or any the parent directories):.git"

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that there is an empty `.git` directory in your project that's causing Xcode to believe there to be a repository there.

Comment: After read your comment I ran "git init" on Terminal.app. Guess What? It started to work... Weird